# 日本語に違和感: 投稿を削除する時に「投票を削除しますか?」と聞かれる

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

[image: この投票を削除しますか?]

1. 自分の質問や回答の「削除」リンクをクリック
2. 上のようなダイアログが表示される

Answer (score 1):

> この投稿を削除しますか？

質問と回答で文言を分けられるのであれば、

> この質問を削除しますか？
>   この回答を削除しますか？

のように分けたがほうがよいかもしれません。

Comment: 分けると全サイトにも適用するため、とりあえず「投稿」を「ポスト」に入れ替える。カテゴリーとして大枠は「ポスト」で、ポストの中に「質問」と「回答」がある。